# Referencing SharedModule in AppModule

Tags: angular

That might be a silly question, I thing I'm making it harder than it really is, but I have **Shared** and **Core** modules. I have for example a **SpinnerComponent** (spinner loading icon). means, every component in the app should show a spinner while loading, that is fine. The **SpinnerComponent** is in hour **SharedModule**. Thing is, we have also a component in the **app.component** which we need to show a spinner. Should I reference **SharedModule** in **AppModule** as well? Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should inject the **`SharedModule`** to your **`AppModule`** since **`SpinnerComponent`**  is used.

This is the suggested way as well.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule      
        })
    ]
```

Comment: That is what I was supposing. Should I inject it as forRoot?

Comment: yes if your class has `forRoot()` static method returning `ModuleWithProviders`'s object (example: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/feature-modules.html). Here is an explanation what is forRoot method or: angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-the-forroot-method.